# Fade div to black on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to `fadeout` my top image  when I scroll down, so that it is completely black by the time it has scrolled off the page and completely normal when I am at the top of the page.

This is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KCb5z/12/).

This section of code:

```
<div class="jumbo midheight">
   test<br />test
</div>
```

I have my background color as black so I was thinking it would be smart just to `fadeout` my background-image element but it seems that isn't possible.

Does this mean I have to put an overlay onto the `div` itself?

And if so, how do I do it?

Ideally I'd like to avoid adding an overlay `div` on top but I think I might have to.

Comment: You can't fade background images - just the whole element.  You'll need an individual element (either an img or a div with a background image) and fade that instead.  Look at `$(window).on("scroll")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to fade it to black, so - no, you can't fade a background image, but that's easy enough to get around. I used an overlay. I just positioned the div with the background image relative. Put another div inside and called it black overlay along with some added css and js.
CSS:

```
#blackOverlay{background-color:#000;opacity:0.0;position:absolute;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;}
```

JS:

```
  $('#blackOverlay').css('opacity',currentScrollTop/$('#blackOverlay').height());
```

Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KCb5z/21/

I took out your js for simplicity, but you can see what I was going for there.  that should get you started.

- edit just saw you said you didn't want to use an overlay, but why not? easy solution.

Answer (score 3):

What Archer said is correct. The logic for the scrolling to fadeout is pretty simple. Just calculate the alpha value depending on your current scrolltop value.

I extended your sample with this:

http://jsfiddle.net/KCb5z/15/

to mention:

```
...
var currentJumboAlpha = Math.max(1 - ((currentScrollTop * 100 / jumboHeight) / 100), 0);
...
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: That does help, thank you. What about if I made jumbo background-color: black and then put my image in an image tag inside it, then fade that out?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use an overlay div. This answer is aimed at being simpler than the other two, but they seem to work effectively too

http://jsfiddle.net/jabark/KCb5z/20/

JS:

```
function CheckScroll(el) {
    var topVal = el.outerHeight(true);
    var bottom_of_object = el.offset().top + topVal;
    var top_of_window = $(window).scrollTop();
    var amountOff = bottom_of_object - top_of_window;
    var opacity = amountOff / topVal;
    el.find('#FadeMe').css('opacity',opacity);
}

$(window).scroll(function(){
    CheckScroll($('.jumbo'));        
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="jumbo midheight">
    <div id="FadeMe"> </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#FadeMe {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:400px;
    width:100%;
    background-image: url("http://www.vlime.co.nz/images/buttons/backgroundimage.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
.jumbo {
    background: black;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: it only takes one line of code, how is this more efficient?

Comment: please point me to the part of my answer where I said mine was more efficient?

Comment: well, you edited it but it certainly isn't simpler either. Not that there is anything wrong with it, i'm just wondering how 30 lines of code is simpler than the total of 3 for html css and js that makes it work.

Comment: If I had edited it, it would state that I had edited it. Like yours says "Edited 18 mins ago", mine does not.

Simpler because, it handles many circumstances. You can take mine, drop it in anywhere, point at any element and it should just work. At the point of writing my answer, yours wouldn't work if:
1) the height of the container was not 600px
2) the container was not at the top of the page

Comment: see the edit, since you used my css yours only works with a 400px container too. granted if the element isn't at the top yours is better - not simpler. Good addition though. +1

Comment: Yes I saw the edit :). I set it to 400px because that's how big the OP set their element. Although you are right, it does make sense to have the black as the overlay and not the image and therefore have 100% height and width without too much trouble.